# TypeError: Invalid input for linprog: A_ub must be a numerical 2D array with each row representing an upper bound inequality constraint

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm doing linear optimization using interior point method.
My optimization code looks like

```
z=scipy.optimize.linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, bounds=bounds,method='interior-point',
                         options = {"maxiter":10000})
```

I have 34K of data. Checked the shape  of A_ub using below code

```
A_ub.shape
Out[7]: (37439, 74878)
```

Initially same code ran for 8K data but now it's throwing error

```
TypeError: Invalid input for linprog: A_ub must be a numerical 2D array with each row representing an upper bound inequality constraint
```

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Show us type(A_ub)

Comment: @RichardRublev `type(A_ub)
Out[11]: numpy.ndarray`

Comment: This is not enough information (and we can't run that code). My best guess (having hacked on that code in the past): your memory blows up and the design of this functions exception-handling effects in this message (which is misleading). With code available, you can learn from [this part of the sources](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8047001cfdf54b2d2396c89f91340442ed75c082/scipy/optimize/_linprog_util.py#L149).

Answer (score -1):

I found this example from old code

```
from scipy import optimize
    optimize.linprog(
...     c = [1, 3], 
...     A_ub=[[1, 1]], 
...     b_ub=[4],
...     bounds=(1, 6),
...     method='interior-point'
... )
     con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: 4.00000000831602
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 4
   slack: array([2.])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([1., 1.])
```

Of course you can use simple or any other method. May be you should check memory,you are dealing with large arrays.